# NavigationMixin to standard__objectPage passing recordType value

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

I want to navigate to a new record creation passing recordType but I don't see nothing in doc that allows me to do that.

I understand you can't predifined values for now but, is recordTypeId allowed at least?

Do you have to put it on `state` object attribute?

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type : 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes : {
            actionName : 'new',
            objectApiName : objectApiName
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:-

```
showNewOpportunityForm(recordTypeId) {
   this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
       type: 'standard__objectPage',
       attributes: {
       objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
       actionName: 'new',
   },
   state: {
      recordTypeId: recordTypeId,
   }
 });
}
```

You can mention the recordtypeId in state. Also, You can upvote this idea :-

[Allow setting pre-default values in record form by navigation service in LWC](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CYGkQAO)